# Call Core Data Objects from different file SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

Right now, I have to do the CRUD on the same view file because every time I try to move it to a different file and call it on the view with a function I get errors. On the code I wrote as comments some explanation too:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var myClass = MyClass()

@FetchRequest(
    entity: ProgrammingLanguage.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ProgrammingLanguage.id, ascending: true)
    ]
) var languages: FetchedResults<ProgrammingLanguage>

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List(languages, id: \.self) { language in
                Text(self.language.name ?? "")
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear{
        // Data not refreshed
        self.myClass.createData()
    }
}
}

class MyClass: ObservableObject {

@FetchRequest(
    entity: ProgrammingLanguage.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ProgrammingLanguage.id, ascending: true)
    ]
) var languages: FetchedResults<ProgrammingLanguage>

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

func createData() {
    for i in 1...5 {
        let language = ProgrammingLanguage(context: self.managedObjectContext)
        language.id = Int32(i)           // << here !!
        language.name = "\(i) SwiftUI"
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
        }
    }
}

func readData() {
    // How can I return the objects here? Not in a loop, but as a fetch request so I can use that fetch request on other views
}
}
```

How can I call Core Data Objects from MyClass to ContentView without having to repeat the same code over and over again?

Right now on the .onAppear() it reads the function but doesn't refresh the data

Comment: The good point about FetchRequest in your view, is that if it changes, your view will update and show new items. If you want to fetch CoreData objects in your class MyClass you can do that, however you need to inform your view about changes with an ObservableObject.

Comment: How would I do all that? I understand the advantage of having it on the same view, but if you have to do the same on 10-100 files, it becomes horrible, besides I have to update every single file separate @davidev

Comment: Why do you have it on multiple views? I have a my MainView which fetchs one entity and then I pass a object to the subviews which displays data. I do not need to fetch it several times.

Comment: That might work even better, how can I pass that from the MainView to a subview? @davidev

Answer (score 0):

I would keep that @FetchRequest, as it is a pretty cool feature of SwiftUI. When you iterate through your items, you pass them to your subviews.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@FetchRequest(
    entity: ProgrammingLanguage.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ProgrammingLanguage.id, ascending: true)
    ]
) var languages: FetchedResults<ProgrammingLanguage>

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

init() 
{
    //here you can call your method of your Manager to create your example data 
    //you to give you an example
    //CoreDataManager.shared.createTestData() 

    for i in 1...5 {
        let language = ProgrammingLanguage(context: self.managedObjectContext)
        language.id = Int32(i)           // << here !!
        language.name = "\(i) SwiftUI"
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
        }
    }

}

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(languages, id: \.self) { language in
                    //Here we pass a single language entity to our subview
                    //If that subview makes changes to that object, these changes will detected in this view here
                    Subview(language: language)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Subview: View 
{
    var language: ProgrammingLanguage

    var body: some View 
    {
        Text(self.language.name ?? "")
    }
}
```

You just pass the language to your subview and can access these values there. Language is a object of the `ProgrammingLanguage` class, which gets automatically created by CoreData. If you make changes to that object, even in the subview, these changes can be displayed in the `ContentView`. You can also pass your languages as array to your subview if you need to.

**Edit:** I haven't tested that example code. It should just give you are brief example how to pass your objects to the next view, and display these attributes there.

However, outsourcing your CoreData activites does make sense for sure. I use a CoreData Manager, which I implemented with a Singleton approach, which deals with creating new objects, saving context...

Comment: What if I want to define a function on another class and run it on that subView? Let's say on the .onAppear{} of that NavigationView in the mainView. An example could be of creating/deleting data. So I have 1 function in 1 class and I can call it on multiple files/views

Comment: Yes thats possible. You can call that create method in the init method of your view, to create your example data. See above in the init method.

Comment: In which init method? Refere to my example on the post, how can I call the loop on onAppear on a void function on another class so I create those values?

Comment: @Spyky You can just add that to any view struct in the init method. You can also call that in your subviews, which will make changes to the CoreData and these changes will be detected by the FetchResult which updates the view accordingly

Comment: I think you don't understand me. I don't want to use views, I'm trying to move the logic outside of the view. I updated the question above with the new code. If you look in `class MyClass` I have the function `createData`, it compiles but no data is showed, maybe the UI is not aware of changes? Also if you see, I'm repeating the same fetch request code on both files, how can I implement this fetch request only on `readData()`?